# How to match a URL from a tab with an Array of URL's - Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So far I have this:

```
// So we can notify users
    var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
    'icon-48.png',  
    'Alert!', 
    'abcdefghijklmnop'
);
      // Called when the url of a tab changes.
      function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
        // Compare with a the URL
        if (tab.url.indexOf('example.com') > -1) {
          //then
          chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
          notification.show();
        }
      };

      // Listen for any changes to the URL of any tab.
      chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);
```

Instead of simply comparing with example.com as above I would like to check the URL against an Array of URL's. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same, except you would loop through the array:

```
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  for (var i = 0, iLen = urlArray.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    if (tab.url.indexOf(urlArray[i]) > -1) {
      chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
      notification.show();
      break; // halt for loop
    }
  }
};
```

Another option would be to use a regular expression and use `if (tab.url.match(re))` instead, where `re` could be something like `/example\.com|example\.org|google\.com/`.

Comment: @itsazzad I would simply rewrite the whole logic and use tab.query for this (but maybe there is a better solution) :
`chrome.tabs.query({
    url: ["*://*.google.com/*", "*://*.example.com/*"],
    active: tab.active // pass more tab info
}, function (tabs) {
    console.log(tabs);
});`

[Here is the TABS Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs)
Parameter: [object] queryinfo

Answer (score 0):

If the array is small you can just iterate over it and check.
If it's significantly bigger, Your best method would be to pre-sort it and do a binary serach on it.

Another option can be to concatenate your array to a single string and then just check for an existance in this string (either with `indexOf` or with regex)